Sample space of tossing a coin until heads
In classical probability theory, the probabilities of the elements of the sample space $\Omega$ are defined. In most introductory problems the probability of every element is the same, hence the solution usually just reduces to counting the cardinality of the sample space and the event.
For some reasom today I read was reading Probability by Kinney and found this problem:

Flip a fair coin until heads. What is the probability to get heads in
4 for or less tosses?

And one possible solution if clearly as follows:
$$\Omega = \{H, TH, TTH, TTTH, ...\}$$
And the probability for each element is:
$$ P(H) = \frac{1}{2} \\ P(TH) = \frac{1}{2^2} \\ ... \\ P(TT..H) = \frac{1}{2^n}$$
The probability is $P(\{H, TH, TTH, TTTH\}) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2^4}$.
But then I asked why did I know the probabilities of the elements of $\Omega$? \
All I know are the probabilities of another sample space, namely flip coin once. Then in my mind I applied the "indepence*" of outcome of $n$ flips and got $\frac{1}{2^n}$. (to get a specific sequence the first flip has 1/2 probability the second is idenpendent and also has 1/2...)
But there is hole in this argument if I stick myself to the probability theory up until the point of the book. That only stated what a sample space is, that $P(\Omega) = 1$, $P(A\in Omega) \geq 0$ and $\sum P(A \in Omega) = 1$.
So basically I am wodering how, with that knowledge you can build the probabilities of the statement's sampling space from the sampling space that you actually know the probabilities, flip coin once.
*Independence if applied to events that are the subset of a sampling space what is the sampling space and what are the events? So my argument is kind of informal
I hope this was not very confusing, I guess it is basically a formality question...

It's a little obscured here but the sample space of "flip a fair coin until heads" is actually the entire set of possible sequences of infinite coin flips ${ 0, 1 }^{\mathbb{N}}$. However it is not necessary to phrase the problem this way; since you only care about the probability of getting heads in $4$ or less tosses you can instead say "flip a fair coin until heads or you've flipped $4$ coins," which reduces the sample space back down to a finite set of coin flips ${ 0, 1 }^4$.

@QiaochuYuan Yeah that is reasonable, but what I can't grasp is how you go from defining probabilities for ${0, 1}$ ot probabilities for ${0, 1}^4$

It is just the uniform distribution, each of the possibilities occurs with probability $\frac{1}{2^4}$. Equivalently you force all the coin flips to be independent. This is what the author intends whether or not that was made explicit in the text.

@QiaochuYuan what if now the coin is not fair? $P(H) =p_h$ and $P(T) = p_T$, now each sequence will not be uniform, I was taught that the probability of each element in ${H,T}^4$ would be $P(HTTT) = p_Hp_T^3$ ... Now I an using some independence of each flip to make that calculation, but the theorem says $P(A)P(B) = P(A\cap B)$ and $A, B \in \Omega$ I don't know what is the $\Omega$. Maybe $\Omega = {H, T}$ but then $A$ and be $B$ can only be singletons $H, T$. I apologize if this sounds stupid to you but there is something missing in my understanding...

If the coin isn't fair then you have to write down some products of $p_H$ and $p_T$, yes. $\Omega = { 0, 1 }^4$ is the full set of all $2^4 = 16$ possible coin flips as I said, and each individual coin flip corresponds to one of the $4$ coordinate projections ${ 0, 1 }^4 \to { 0, 1 }$.

@QiaochuYuan I still don't understand but let me sleep on it a while, thanks

I understood two different questions from this:

How to properly model a probability space for this 4 flips experiment?
How is the modelling of the outcome of 4 flips connected to that of 1 flip.

My first answer is more about the second question, that is the connection between the 1 flip experiment and the 4 independent flips experiment.
If you just want a model for the 4 flips experiment, just choose the universe $\Omega$ as the set of all possible combinations, that is $X_1X_2X_3X_4$ where $X_i$ is either $H$ or $T$. That can be written $\Omega=\{H,T\}^4$. For the probability measure, all outcomes are equally likely to happen, that is $\mathbb P(X_1X_2X_3X_4)=\mathbb  P(Y_1Y_2Y_3Y_4)$ for all $X_i,Y_i\in\{H,F\}$. There are $2^4$ possible outcomes so $\mathbb P$ is defined by
$$
\forall X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4\in\{H,F\},\quad\mathbb P(X_1X_2X_3X_4)=\frac{1}{2^4}.
$$
Let $A_i$ denote the event "getting H at exactly the $i$-th flip". Then $A_4=\{TTTH\}$ and $\mathbb P(A_4)=\frac{1}{2^4}$.
Moreover $A_3=\{TTHT,TTHH\}$, so
$$
\mathbb P(A_3)=\mathbb P(TTHT)+\mathbb P(TTHH)=\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^4}=\frac{1}{2^3}\cdot
$$
You can continue with $A_2=\{THHH,THHT,THTT,THTH\}$, or more compactly $A_2=\{THXY\mid X,Y\in\{H,F\}\}$, and $A_1=\{HXYZ\mid X,Y,Z\in\{H,T\}\}$. You easily find $\mathbb P(A_2)=\frac{1}{2^2}$ and $\mathbb P(A_1)=\frac{1}{2}$.
Old answer, more technical
If an experiment is modelled by a probability space $(\mathcal \Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$, then running this experiment $n$ times in independent conditions, that is the outcome of Experience $i$ is not influenced by that of Experience $j\neq i$, can be modelled by the product probability space $(\mathcal \Omega^n,\mathcal F^{\otimes n},\mathbb P^{\otimes n})$. As a reminder, $\mathcal F^{\otimes n}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets $A_1\times\cdots\times A_n$ where $A_1,\cdots,A_n\in\mathcal F$, and $\mathbb P^{\otimes n}$ is such that
$$
\mathbb P^{\otimes n}(A_1\times\cdots\times A_n)=\mathbb P(A_1)\times\cdots\times\mathbb P(A_n).
$$
Now here one experiment corresponds to flipping a coin, which is modelled by $\Omega_0=\{H,T\}$, $\mathcal F_0=\{\emptyset,\{H\},\{T\},\Omega\}$ and $\mathbb P_0$ such that $\mathbb P_0(H)=\mathbb P_0(T)=1/2$.
Flipping the coin 4 times can then be modelled by $\Omega=\Omega_0^4$, $\mathcal F=\mathcal F_0^{\otimes 4}$ and $\mathbb P=\mathbb P_0^{\otimes 4}$.
You did the calculation correctly, but let us write it rigorously as it seems to be the point of the question. Denote by $A_i$ the event "getting $H$ at exactly the $i$-th flip". Then $A_i=\{T\}^{i-1}\times\{H\}\times\Omega_0^{4-i}$. So
$$
\mathbb P(A_i)=\mathbb P_0(T)^{i-1}\times\mathbb P_0(H)\times\mathbb P_0(\Omega_0)^{4-i}=\frac{1}{2^i}\cdot
$$
As the event you are looking for is $A=A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4$ you deduce that
$$
\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P(A_1)+\mathbb P(A_2)+\mathbb P(A_3)+\mathbb P(A_4)=\frac12+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}\cdot
$$

Thanks for the answer, I am afraid this is way over my math knowledge. I don't know if this question will make sense to you: Was the book question out of place, in the sense that the probabilities of the Sample space are basically impossible to get with just the few given until that point? The calculation feels intuitive but to me seems hard to formally justify with the tool I know

I edited my answer accordingly, hope it makes more sense now

I understand you can do $\Omega = {H, T}^4$, but why "For the probability measure, all outcomes are equally likely to happen"? It makes intuitive sense, each of the flips is independent, but I jut can't grasp how you go from the probability of $\Omega ={H,T}$ to $\Omega = {H, T}^4$ maybe be this is what you answered in the second part? If the coin wasn't fair then $\Omega ={H,T}^4$ would not be equaly likely and I guess the probability of each would be $p_H^{n_h} p_T^{n_T}$ but why?

Yes that's essentially the second part of my answer. You could see it with conditional probability if it is more clear: for example with 2 flips, if you denote by $X$ resp. $Y$ the outcome of the first resp. second flip, then $\mathbb P(HT)=\mathbb P(X=H)\mathbb P(Y=T\vert X=H)$. As $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $\mathbb P(Y=T\vert X=H)=\mathbb P(Y=T)$. Hence $\mathbb P(HT)=p_Hp_T$. For example.
